# Google Map marker expanding on different devices

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am trying to use a custom icon for marker in a location based android application and its resizing itself in different devices.

I have 4 different sizes **(drawable-mdpi,drawable-hdpi,drawable-xhdpi,drawable-xxhdpi)** for that icon and paced in different drawable folders.

I am using simple code for using that icon.

```
Bitmap mIconBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.some_icon);

marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(pinOfferLocation)
                                .title("Some Title")
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                        .fromBitmap(mIconBitmap))
                                .snippet("Some Snippet").anchor(0.5f, 1));
```

I also tried using :

```
BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResources(SOME DRAWABLE RESOURCE)
```

Another option I tried was to create a scaled bitmap like this:

```
Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mIconBitmap, 70, 90, true);
```

But the problem with the above line is only good when your application runs in any high density device and it will be extremely scaled on low density devices.

The issue I am facing that the marker icons are not resizing itself according to different devices.

Is there a better way to use an icon in google maps for different device sizes?

Any help is really appreciated.. thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think I had a similar problem. I used this workaround, even it is not very beautiful.

I loaded the bitmap from asset-folder using this method:

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromAsset(Context context, String strName,
        int sampleFactor) {
    AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();

    InputStream istr;
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try {
        Options opt = new Options();
        opt.inSampleSize = sampleFactor;    // IMPORTANT PART
        istr = assetManager.open(strName);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr, null, opt);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }

    return bitmap;
}
```

The sample factor can be extracted using something like this:

```
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();

    // not sure if this is just testing or necessary for metrics
    getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
            .getMetrics(metrics);

    // factor (adjust in your app)
    int sampleFactorDensity = Math.round(960 / metrics.densityDpi);

    currPosMarker = MyTools.getBitmapFromAsset(this.getActivity(),
            "marker_azure.png", sampleFactorDensity);
```

Comment: Tried your code.. wanted to know if currPosMarker is the Bitmap that we will use in the marker or is the Marker.. trying to implement it but not a success so far.. can you help me out with this ?

Comment: nvm.. got it .. had to create an assets folder and place images there lol.. works but the markers are really small.

Comment: Had to use image with dimensions 250x250 to make it work to a good marker size. Good solution though.